# How can I put my WAMP online for someone to access?

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I would like to briefly open up my computer and allow my business partener to see what I've been developing on the my localhost. I understand there are probably some security issues with this but I only want to open up my computer for a few minutes.

What do I need to setup on the following interfaces to do this?

1. my wireless router
2. windows7
3. WAMP

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works very easily for me on WinXP.

- Fire up the command prompt and enter `ipconfig /all` - get your local IP address
- Log into your router and set up port forwarding to forward HTTP to your local IP address
- Click on your WAMP icon and click again on "Put Online"
- Go to your remote IP (you can find it somewhere like http://www.whatsmyip.org/)

Comment: in windows7, to get local ip. go Win->cmd->ipcib->"ipconfig /all". it's the IPv4 Address...

Comment: On Windows 7, you may also have to check the firewall.  WAMP installs a number of firewall rules.  These relate to the various configurations of the profiles (public, private, domain) as well as protocol type (UDP, TCP).  You may have to edit the "block" rules to allow access to your HTTP port.

Comment: There is a guide I wrote for Windows in general, you may want to check it out: http://www.simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/

Answer (score 4):

Another option is simply using a tunnelling service like:

- [pagekite.net](http://pagekite.net)
- [forwardhq.com](http://forwardhq.com)
- [progrium.com/localtunnel/](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/)

Localtunnel is open source, while the others require you to pay a small monthly fee after a trial period.

Comment: Another great, free, 1 command line solution for tunneling - ngrok.io

Answer (score 2):

To allow external connections to your server you have to restart WAMP in online mode.

Left-click the WAMP icon and select Put Online.

Wait for the icon status to change to white again.

Enter your IP into your web browser bar and hit enter.

If you get the same forbidden page as before hit F5 to let the browser load the newest version.

If it's still not working you probably have to enable port 80 forwarding in your router configuration.

Finally your buddy can see your homepage!

Answer (score 1):

If your Apache server is up and running already on your localhost, then you should just be able to set up a route within your router to point at your computer for traffic coming IN on port 80.

EDIT: I just checked my router settings, and it calls this 'services'. It allows incoming requests on a specific port to be listened to, and forwards the request onto a specific computer (by IP) attached to the router.

You would be better asking this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

- make sure the incoming traffic on port 80 is not blocked by your firewall or ISP - [see this video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_open_port.html)
- then, configure your Router to forward:
  incoming requests to your External IP port 80 towards your Internal IP port 80 - [video demo here](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_portforward.html)
- finally test if port open - [video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_test.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors (outside of the actual WAMP server) that will all prevent requests coming in from outside (e.g., from the internet) from reaching the running Apache server.

First, you need to make sure you have a static IP address, and preferably also a registered domain name with an "A" record (DNS) set to that IP address - for both the `ServerName` and all the `ServerAlias` hosts (i.e., 'www') that are used in the VirtualHost.

Otherwise, if you have a dynamic IP address, use a Dynamic DNS client to sync the changing IP address with the domain name's DNS records.

Then:

1. You'll need to open Windows Firewall to allow incoming port 80 (http) and port 443 (https) TCP packets.
2. You'll need to "port-forward" ports 80 and 443 in the Router (your WiFi box) to the LAN IP of the server.
3. You'll need to check if your ISP is blocking incoming port 80 (and 443) requests. If it is, you'll need to change the port this VirtualHost is listening-on\binding-to. You can make this test by using an outside proxy website and entering `http://your.public.ip.address/` for the URL to visit. If the request times out, it never made it through. Afterwards, when you change the port for the VirtualHost, test again with URL `http://your.public.ip.address:port/` (try port 8080).

Taken from [Enabling Internet Access of Websites (for WAMP servers)](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/enabling-internet-access-of-websites)

Answer (score 0):

changing the port from 80 to another port number will work perfect,and please note that changing the port will require a new inbond rule on your firewall and changes on httpd.config file

Comment: need more explanation, read how to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Why should changing the port of the webserver solve the problem? Why not forward the existing port 80?