# Setting up local wireless server using WAMP

Tags: networking, wamp

My goal is to have two laptops in a network. One is acting as a server, serving webpages to the other. The catch here is that neither is connected to the outside internet.

What I have done so far is setup WAMP on the server laptop, and it successfully serves web pages on localhost. Now I want to access these pages on the other laptop.

To do this, I had the server create an ad-hoc network and connected the other laptop to it, but I'm stuck - and I'm worried I'm not on the right track. I followed [this](http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/setting-up-a-localhost) tutorial but in the end I figured out that just explained how to spoof a text URL as an IP address, and not really what I was looking for.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is my method the best way to do this (with ad-hoc networks)? Is there some way to connect a laptop to a wireless router and have the laptop act as a server to another laptop?
2. If my WAMP and ad-hoc network should work, how do I connect other laptops to my server through the ad-hoc network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the first option: get a wifi router. Then you can assign static IP adresses from the routers private network or use DHCP server on the router. Hopefully you will have an option to reserve IP adresses on DHCP server so you dont have to check every time what IP adress the laptop acting as a server got. You use this address to access your web server. Also, you can use this router later as a gateway to the internet if you want.

In ad hoc mode you will probably get an address from 169.254.0.0/16 link-local scope, and you can check it by running `ipconfig` as @Robadob already suggested.

Comment: Thanks! The router idea seems to be a better option. Do you have links that would explain how do set this up? Sorry for the noobish questions, these seem very google-able however I can't seem to get good results - I probably don't know the right keywords. So if I understand properly: connect server laptop to router using wired ethernet, and obtain the IP of the laptop (preferably static). Run WAMP pointing at that IP. Connect client laptop wirelessly to router, and go to that IP in the browser?

Comment: The majority of consumer routers will work out of the box, with the exception of static IP address. You will need to go through router options to find if the router supports it and if it does it is not something complicated to configure. I can't tell you the exact procedure since it varies from router to router. You don't need to connect a laptop by cable if you don't want to, it will work the same if you use wifi on both laptops. And yes, you just start WAMP on the server laptop and type its IP address as a link in client laptop.

Answer (score 1):

On your hosting laptop open cmd and call `ipconfig` look for the internal IP address on the network interface your hosting the ad-hoc network.
Enter that IP address into the browser on your client laptops web browser instead of localhost.

If that doesn't work, try other ip addresses listed by `ipconfig` (incase you used the wrong) and then check the properties of your ad-hoc network, windows firewall and any other firewall software to disable anything that might be blocking it.

An ad-hoc network is suitable option for what your doing, most people would probably use a switch or router though, however that requires hardware you probably don't have.

Comment: Do you have more details on using a router? If all I need is a standard wireless router I do have access to those, I'm just not sure how to set it up as network that is not connected to the outside internet. Unless it is as simple as plug in server, connect client, go to server's IP?

Comment: Ah, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003644/how-can-i-put-my-wamp-online-for-someone-to-access

Comment: It's as simple as setup a wireless network on the router and don't plug the router into the network, connect both computers to the router and repeat what I gave in my answer. However I don't know enough about ad-hoc networks (without researching) to specify any advantage that has over a router or vice versa.

Comment: Not like that, port forwarding is only required if you wish to make your website available to the internet, which you do not. A router should not block internal connections by default.