# Making my wamp website public

Tags: web, makefile, wamp, public

Hello everyone I downloaded wamp yesterday and i got a functional fusion CMS site my problem is i can´t make my website public i ve seen many guides and stuff and none of them actually works i ve seen that i have to edit something in apache config file and  Allow /deny other ips the thing is i can´t even find that.... i m currently using 2.4.9 apache i hope some one can help me with this i even tryed to find a config file online to download but i could not find any this is my last resource :/ have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

Look into this SO question: [How can i put my WAMP online for someone to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003644/how-can-i-put-my-wamp-online-for-someone-to-access)

And for a more recent answer look into this link: [simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver](http://simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver)

As far as the config file goes- don't look for it online. Its there in wamp folder somewhere like: c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Thank you! those links have been very usefull!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find this answer useful do approve/accept it.