# FileNotFound exception Wamp server

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

I am trying to create a basic android login screen wherein I am using php,MySQL and wamp server. The wamp server is running on my laptop and I have a file named login.php in www folder. But when I am running my app through my device (mobile) it throws an error like file not found at 192.168.x.x/login.php.  I have tried using 10.0.2.2 and the ipv4 address of my laptop but both are not working. However when I try to access same url i.e. 192.168.x.x/login.php though my browser on laptop, I can access the php file but the same file is not accessible though android app. Can anyone please suggest me anything on this issue.

Comment: why don't you just make your WAMP server public? All you have to do is configure your router settings and provide your WAMP server with a port. Here's an link to some more information [How can i put my WAMP online for someone to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003644/how-can-i-put-my-wamp-online-for-someone-to-access). This will be accessible by any device on any network. And as for your current problem, can you try using an android emulator on your laptop and see if the result is the same instead of your phone/device.

Comment: Try to use a browser on your device! Your device should have a wifi connection with the same router as your laptop has. You are unclear about your setup.

Comment: Both laptop an mobile are connected to same wifi